# Download from Android using ftp://user:password@url

Tags: java, android, ftp

The following code works from command line Java on Windows, but does not work on Android device connected via WiFi. No Apache client used, just simple class using URL as below.

When replacing my FTP by test HTTP URL `h??p://google.com`, it works. What could be the cause? Is the URL library different?

```
final String ftpRoot  = "user:password@myftp/path";
ftp.downloadFile(destPath+"/list","ftp://"+ftpRoot+"/")); //URL + "/" returns FTP directory listing
public synchronized boolean downloadFile (String localfilename,String ftpPath){

try{
    URL url = new URL(ftpPath);
    m_client = url.openConnection();
    m_client.connect(); //here connection fails at Android but works in command line
    ...
```

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the Android device can route network traffic to the server in question?  Does the code work with some other ftp server on the public internet, or does it only seem to work with http ?

Comment: It does succeed to connect using Google Chrome from the device,also using ftp://user:password@ftp format.

Comment: What is format ftp://user:password@url/path/file at all? Did anyone see documentation? I suspect that is supported by Wininet , browsers and FTP clients unofficially, that's why does not work at low level.